# Apache camel file component not moving files

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using apache camel 2.12.1 to create a route and then move some files in my local directory, the exmple runs fine but the files are never moved, this is the code for the class.

```
public class MoveFilesTest {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MoveFilesTest.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        LOG.debug("create CamelContext");
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        // add our route to the CamelContext
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            File file = null;
            public void configure() {
                from("file:data/inbox?delay=100&noop=true")
                .process( new Processor() {

                    public void process(Exchange msg) throws Exception {
                        File file = msg.getIn().getBody(File.class);
                        LOG.debug("Processing file: " + file.getName());

                    }
                })

                .to("file:data/outbox").end();
            }
        });

        LOG.debug("start the route and let it do its work");
        context.start();

        context.stop();

    }
}
```

as a note, this code just to work, now i'm working on mac os x 10.7, this is the debug log. i added the noop=false and the delete=true, but the result is the same. thank you

```
DEBUG [main] (MoveFilesTest.java:24) - create CamelContext
DEBUG [main] (MoveFilesTest.java:45) - start the route and let it do its work
 INFO [main] (DefaultCamelContext.java:1498) - Apache Camel 2.12.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
 INFO [main] (ManagedManagementStrategy.java:187) - JMX is enabled
 INFO [main] (DefaultTypeConverter.java:50) - Loaded 176 type converters
 INFO [main] (DefaultCamelContext.java:1689) - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
 INFO [main] (FileEndpoint.java:83) - Endpoint is configured with noop=true so forcing endpoint to be idempotent as well
 INFO [main] (FileEndpoint.java:89) - Using default memory based idempotent repository with cache max size: 1000
 INFO [main] (DefaultCamelContext.java:2183) - Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[file://data/inbox?delay=100&noop=true]
 INFO [main] (DefaultCamelContext.java:1533) - Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
 INFO [main] (DefaultCamelContext.java:1534) - Apache Camel 2.12.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 8.936 seconds
 INFO [main] (DefaultCamelContext.java:1706) - Apache Camel 2.12.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
 INFO [main] (DefaultShutdownStrategy.java:172) - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
 INFO [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] (DefaultShutdownStrategy.java:600) - Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[file://data/inbox?delay=100&noop=true]
 INFO [main] (DefaultShutdownStrategy.java:217) - Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
 INFO [main] (DefaultCamelContext.java:1780) - Apache Camel 2.12.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 8.953 seconds
 INFO [main] (DefaultCamelContext.java:1781) - Apache Camel 2.12.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.013 seconds
```

Comment: A good idea is to read javadoc, such as the API on CamelContext, and the start method you use to start Camel, it explains why: http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CamelContext.start` does not block, so basically you are starting the context and then immediately stopping it. You need to wait or block on something until the context should stop. You can reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846791/camelcontext-start-doesnt-block) for some ways of doing this.

Comment: It worked fine, thank you, now i'll try to integrate it to my project.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you start Camel and stop it immediately. So, when you put a file to a folder. It wont process cuz camel is already stopped.

Camel contains `Main` implementation to keep Camel running in standalone application.

There is link: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but that was to do with streamCaching() not getting set properly and so the code below was failing

```
    context.getStreamCachingStrategy().setSpoolDirectory(spoolDirectory);
    from(uri.toString()).streamCaching().to(destination);
```

I  set the Streaming directly on CamelContext and that solved the problem

```
    CamelContext context = getContext();
    context.setStreamCaching(true);
    context.getStreamCachingStrategy().setSpoolDirectory(localSpoolDirectory);
    context.getStreamCachingStrategy().setSpoolThreshold(Long.parseLong(spoolThreshold.trim()));
    context.getStreamCachingStrategy().setBufferSize(Integer.parseInt(bufferSize.trim()));
```